# How to toggle hide/show of all elements with same class name on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to toggle hide/show on all divs with the same class. I have a few tables on my page with multiple strings in each row. I only show the first string and have the rest of the strings in a div that's hidden with style='display:none;'.

I just cannot get this to work. Any suggestions?

example of html:

```
<a href=# onClick='toggleHist(\"".$zone."\");return false;'>Additional Info</a>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>asdfasdf   <div class='zone_1' style='display:none;'>asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
     asdfasdf<div class='zone_1' style='display:none;'> asdfasdf asdfasdf asfasdf </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
     adfasdf<div class='zone_1' style='display:none;'> asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

My javascript:

```
function toggleHist(zone_name){
    //alert(zone_name);
    $('.'+zone_name).toggle();

}
```

Using .show(); and .hide(); both work, but toggle won't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `.toggleClass()`? http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to `.toggle()`

You can create a css class containing `display: none` and use `.toggleClass()` to toggle that class on the elements.

```
.DisplayNone
{
    display: none;
}


function toggleHist(zone_name){

    $('.'+zone_name).toggleClass('DisplayNone');

}
```

Or you can use show and hide by checking to see if the elements are visible.

```
function toggleHist(zone_name){    

    if ($('.'+zone_name).is(":visible")) 
         $('.'+zone_name).hide();        
    else
         $('.'+zone_name).show();

}
```

Comment: I used your second suggestion and it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `show()` works, `hide()` works, but `toggle()` doesn't, I see only one explanation: your event is triggered twice (or any even amount).

Comment: that's what the alert was for - it's only coming through once. good spot though.